# How to increase graphics memory in Mac OS running as a client in VMware?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization

I have installed Mac OS in VMware today and its default settings are as follow:

[image]

How can i configure the virtual workstation to increase the graphics memory to 512MB from the present value of 128MB?

Comment: @tlhintoq - what version of mac osx are you using? the mavericks version?

Comment: It says "OS X 10.8" in the screenshot, which would be Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 9):

VMware's knowledge base article, [Setting Custom Video Memory Size in Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1001876), shows the setting to change:

> ### Setting Custom Video Memory Size in Fusion
>
> There is no way to choose a different video memory size through the
>   user interface. It must be done by editing the virtual machine
>   settings (`.vmx`) file. For more information, [see Editing the .vmx file
>   for your Fusion virtual machine (1014782)](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1014782).
>
> Add this line to the .vmx file:
>
> `svga.vramSize = value_in_bytes`
>
> where value_in_bytes is the desired memory size in bytes

The `.vmx` mentioned in the article is hidden within your virtual machine's bundle. To find the file to edit, right-click (or Control-click) on your virtual machine in the Finder and 
 select **Show Package Contents**.

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed OS X on VMWare workstation for Windows, you need [VMsvga2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmsvga2/). 
Install that .pkg file inside OS X and you'll see a noticeable change in the animations.

You'll also find updated versions of VMsvga2 for Mavericks inside Files section. You are required to install all required patches & updates for everything to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had weird rendering issues in 10.8.4 such as AppCode or muCommander not drawing their UI. This driver fixed it.

Comment: For what it is worth using OSX on non Apple hardware, virtualized or not, is against the EULA.

Comment: Messaged can't install on macOS High Sierra that Hosted on windows workstation pro 14.

Comment: To remove the `VMsvga2.kext` after the installation of the `VMsvga2*.pkg` open the terminal and type: sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/VMsvga2.kext enter your password and wait for it to complete and restart.

Comment: @dwightk ....

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to take a snapshot before you install SVGA2.  On my MacVM the SVGA2 driver kills a couple programs like iPhoto and Safari.  Now I can't find a way to remove it.  Dummy me for not taking a snapshot because I was in a hurry.